# Excel - filter table & pivot table at the same time

Tags: excel

I have one Excel Table and one Pivot Table (from this Table). I need to filter both at the same time with the same Slicer. It is easy for 2 Pivot Tables, but I don't know how to do that for 1 Pivot Table and 1 Table.

I put 2 slicers next to each other (like from Pivot Table and Table), but the user must click 2 times if he/she wants to filter it.

Thank you.

Comment: You  need VBA for this. I have described a way to sync two table slicers (named Slicer_City1 and Slicer_City2) with a pivot slicer named Slicer_City here: https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/slicers04.asp?AllComments=True#27457

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. :-(

Comment: The code mentioned will likely need adjustments, post your questions overthere or here along with the code and the problems you are experiencing.